# Mysql Error 1064 ("You have an error in your SQL syntax") triggered by SQL comments

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a series of scripts for creating a schema, with a comment like the following before each instruction:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Table TABLE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------
```

When I execute the script from mysql on the command line, I get a bunch of errors like the following:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '------------------------------------------------------
------------------------' at line 1
```

(actually, I get one error for each comment, in spite of the message always referring to line 1).

To quickly solve my problem I simply removed the comments and the script ran without problems, but I was surprised to see such a behaviour and to be unable to find a relevant question here on stackoverflow. Does anyone have an explanation? Did anyone ever observe such an odd behaviour?

I am running mysql 5.6.30, the default for 5.6 on ubuntu at this time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html):

> From a “-- ” sequence to the end of the line. In MySQL, the “-- ”
>   (double-dash) comment style **requires the second dash to be followed by**
>   **at least one whitespace or control character** (such as a space, tab,
>   newline, and so on). This syntax differs slightly from standard SQL
>   comment syntax, as discussed in Section 1.8.2.4, “'--' as the Start of
>   a Comment”.

(Emphasis Mine)

**tl;DR** Your `--` indicating a comment must be followed by at least one whitespace or control character.

Fixed code of yours:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
--  Table TABLE_NAME
-- -----------------------------------------------------
```

In MySQL You can also use this syntax:

```
/* 
*    Table TABLE_NAME
*/
```

Or even this:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------
#   Table TABLE_NAME
# -----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: And, unlike Oracle syntax, MySql allows comments `/* in this style */` as well as `-- in this style`.

Comment: @OllieJones Even `# in this style` :D

Comment: I accepted this answer as the most complete. I am used to full lines of dashes interpreted as comments in SQL, so I was surprised to see that they raised errors. I will inform the providers of the software I am installling that the content of their "mysql" software is actually not MySQL-compliant :)

Answer (score 3):

You need a space after two dashes to indicate a comment. Without it it is just a string:

```
-- ------------------------------------------------------
--  Table TABLE_NAME
-- ------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I only use the two dashes `--` when commenting a single line.  When working with block comments, I tend to use the following format:

```
/**
 * Table TABLE_NAME
 *
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

From:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html
The space after double dash i.e. "-- " is part of the comment identification!
Rationale behind MySQL decision: is here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html

> The space is required to prevent problems with automatically generated
>   SQL queries that use constructs such as the following, where we
>   automatically insert the value of the payment for payment:

```
UPDATE account SET credit=credit-payment
UPDATE account SET credit=credit--1
```